# Increase number of outgoing WCF connections wsHttpBinding

Tags: web-services, wcf, connection, iis-8, wshttpbinding

I have a pair of Win 2012 servers running as a web-server and WCF-server and I want to increase the number of outgoing connections from the web-server to the WCF-server (which appears to be limited to 24)

- Windows 2012 R2
- 2 CPUs (each server)
- IIS 8.5 (Integrated App Pools)
- ASP.NET 3.5 WebForms App
- wsHttpBinding
- WCF v3.5 Service

I have proved that the WCF server can handle more than 24 concurrent connections (by loading the WCF WSDL with JMeter and 800 threads) - so this is pointing me to believe that the ASP.NET outgoing connections are being throttled.

[image: WCF Server Current Connections]

I have already tried;

- adding `maxconnections` (into both web and WS web.config files)
- changing `machine.config` `processModel` and `httpRuntime` value (from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/821268))

For example:

```
<connectionManagement>
    <add address="*" maxconnection="96"/>
</connectionManagement>
```

and

```
<processModel  maxWorkerThreads="100" maxIoThreads="100" minWorkerThreads="50" />
<httpRuntime minFreeThreads="176" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="152" />
```

Within the web service I have already tried the service model behaviour settings too (2 CPU's);

```
<serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="32" maxConcurrentSessions="200" maxConcurrentInstances="232"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried to set the `maxConcurrentCalls` in `behavior`? I suspect this can be the issue. You can read more here and how to set in service configuration: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicethrottlingbehavior.maxconcurrentsessions(v=vs.90).aspx  Let me know if this helped

Comment: Hi @RicardoPontual. Yes we already have this set. I didn't mention it in the post as this is a setting within the WCF service (incoming connections). I've updated my post to reflect this now.